# How to use Core-Data best in complex Apps

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

I am a Mac App Dev and have some questions about how to use Core-Data correctly.

I have multiple TableViews and they are all playing around with the same data (which I want to save persistently with Core-Data). I know the central part of Core-Data which I have to work with - `NSManagedObjectContext` and I know how to create `NSManagedObjects` and save/edit/delete these in the persistent store. 
But actually I'm wondering about how to organize all that together with multiple ViewControllers,Views,Tables,.. efficiently **and** without merge conflicts. I've read about some approaches for that: one was by passing the context down from the delegate through every layer of your code. Somebody else suggests to create a singleton-class, let's call it `DatabaseManager`, which holds the `NSManagedObjectContext` instance and you go and ask it from there. (I especially like this approach, don't know why.) Or just ask the delegate every time with `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`, does this have any disadvantages?

Okay, a lot of questions here but that was only about the **How**. Now I want to know about your recommendations of **where** I should actually do all interaction with the **managedObjectsContext**. (to be in compliance with MVC and don't mess up my code and make it more complicated than it has to be..)

- Should I save stuff to Core-Data in my NSTableViewDelegate/-DataSource Classes directly or just fire up an Notification for someone else?
- Should I implement some instance methods for my Model-Objects (like `-(void)saveInstanceToDatabase`,..) to encapsulate Core-Data-Interaction?

Ok thanks in advance for all the brave guys who read until this point and give me some kind of response :D I always appreciate code-examples!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After years of working with Core Data... I've come to the conclusion it's not very good. There are some serious  flaws in it's design that can only be solved properly by abstracting the whole thing away.

I recommend implementing your own model for manage objects, which uses core data underneath but does not ever expose it.

Your views and controllers and application delegate and all of that should not ever touch core data at all. They should talk to a series of classes you create yourself, which has been custom tailored for your particular application.

That object layer can use core data underneath, or it might use something else like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) or [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/protocols/nscoding_protocol/reference/reference.html) or even just plain old `NSData` objects (this is the fastest option, if you need extremely high performance with large amounts of data, especially when combined with features like `NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe`).

Start with Core Data. Look at the other options if you have problems. Having your own layer on top means you can easily abandon it in future. And *many* developers have chosen to move away from Core Data shortly after their app ships to the public. Often due to unsolvable bugs or performance issues.